# Is it possible to use JFrog Artifactory as a remote for NVM

Tags: artifactory, nvm

Due to some networking requirements, we have a case where we'd like to be able to use JFrog Artifactory as mirror for NVM. Is this possible?

I found a guide [here](https://sionwilliams.com/posts/2020-12-09-node-n-npm-mirror/) but it appears to no longer be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a Generic remote repository in Artifactory points to https://nodejs.org/dist/ in a similar way as mentioned in the guide linked in the question.

Note that in case trying to test the connection in the the repository configuration in Artifactory UI the result might be a “403” response returned from nodejs, however, it should still be possible to pull artifacts via curl/wget through Artifactory, for example:

```
$ curl -u <user>:<password> "http://<Artifactory-URL>/<Remote-Repository>/index.json"
```